# OFM rwrun - generating different pdf format compare to printer output

Tags: oracle, report

1. I am using oracle report rwrun command in VC++ to generate report which directly goes to printer (destype=printer).
2. Now I want to get this same report in PDF file, for this I only changed destype=file and given file name in desname=xyz.pdf.

The issue i am facing here is PDF generated in 2nd case is in different format compare to print in 1st case. Please check below images for pdf format green box is content area.

1.[Correct PDF format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLp4H.jpg)             2. [Incorrect PDF format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BguYW.jpg)

I tried changing Orientation to Portrait but not getting desired format.

Please suggest the solution to get same PDF like I am getting in case of destype=printer